# Is subjunctive optional in English?

Tags: grammar

> I wish I were able to fly.
>
> I wish I was able to fly.

Is subjunctive optional in English? If so, are these two equivalent? I heard there were 12 tenses in English and subjunctive present or past are not among the 12.

Comment: Modern grammar doesn't recognise a subjunctive mood, especially the ill-named past subjunctive (the kind with "were"); rather, it calls this use of "were" an irrealis mood, a formal alternant to the perfectly acceptable modal preterite "was".

Comment: well, Bill, that's kind of a distinction without a difference, since the traditional use of the subjunctive includes the irrealis. The problem with "I wish I was" is that it might clash with a different trend in English, i.e. the (regrettable) replacement of "If I had done it" by "If I did it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wish I were able to fly

is the correct subjunctive form in English. It is the correct form to use when writing or speaking formally, and some would say the way one should aspire to speak at all the time. You would certainly get [brownie points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownie_points) from a lot of native English speakers.

> I wish I was able to fly.

is also a perfectly acceptable way to indicate a subjunctive sense (ie a sense that something is indefinite, or an aspiration, etc). It is *marginally* less formal, and some people will still insist it is 'wrong' (wrongly). However to call it informal, given that it is almost ubiquitous in all sorts of speech and writing, is really not an accurate description.

The use of 'were' to form the English subjunctive is probably dying out because it's not really needed, and quite a few of the other [subjunctive forms mentioned here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) are also rare or optional.

I should be noted, however, that American English speakers tend to use the traditional subjunctive forms marginally more often. To British English speakers, this can sometimes sound like hypercorrection or pretentiousness, especially when used in informal speech contexts. I used to think that American English speakers using 'were' subjunctives in sitcoms were examples of writers writing 'proper' English instead of realistic spoken English. I was wrong.

Comment: *I wish I* ***could*** *fly* is perfectly fine, and it's not in the subjunctive. (Which answers the literal title of the question.)